# batch script copying file from only the last line of given text file

Tags: batch-file, file-copying

I am trying to copy different file in given folder from a text file (line by line) and by using some specific keywords in lines but it is copying file from the last line. I am new in batch scripting so I don't know too much about syntax of batch script my code is

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
mkdir events_sorted
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in (input.txt) do set id=%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d%%e

for /r /d %%i in (.) do (
    cd %%i
    copy "%id%-00S.*" "%CD%/events_sorted/"
 )

pause
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the `for /R` loop into your `for /F` loop by placing `(` after `do` and putting `)` at the end before `pause`. In addition, do not store the line string in variable `id`, simply use the line string directly within the `copy` command line. Furthermore, do not use `cd %%i`, but use `%%i` immediately rather than `%CD%`. Here is the fixed code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

mkdir "events_sorted"
for /F "usebackq tokens=3-7" %%a in ("input.txt") do (
    for /R /D %%i in (.) do (
        copy "%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d%%e-00S.*" "%%~i/events_sorted/"
    )
)
pause

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: I have tried nested for loop but it is not copying even single file  same as with this fixed code.

Comment: Remove `@echo off` temporarily and check what happens; do not run the batch file by double-clicking its icon, open a `cmd` window, manoeuvre to the parent directory by `cd /D` and run the batch file by typing its name instead, so you can read every echoed command and potential error messages. Since I do not know your directory structure, your files nor the content of `input.txt`, I cannot do more at this point...

Comment: The question is also where are the source files located?